# Combinatorics and Probability Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations

The problem I am working on is:

An ATM personal identification number (PIN) consists of four digits, each a 0, 1, 2, . . . 8, or 9, in succession.

a.How many different possible PINs are there if there are no restrictions on the choice of digits?

b.According to a representative at the author’s local branch
of Chase Bank, there are in fact restrictions on the choice
of digits. The following choices are prohibited: (i) all four
digits identical (ii) sequences of consecutive ascending or
descending digits, such as 6543 (iii) any sequence start-ing with 19 (birth years are too easy to guess). So if one of the PINs in (a) is randomly selected, what is the prob-ability that it will be a legitimate PIN (that is, not be one of the prohibited sequences)?

c. Someone has stolen an ATM card and knows that the first
and last digits of the PIN are 8 and 1, respectively. He has
three tries before the card is retained by the ATM (but
does not realize that). So he randomly selects the $2nd$ and $3^{rd}$
digits for the first try, then randomly selects a different pair of digits for the second try, and yet another randomly selected pair of digits for the third try (the
individual knows about the restrictions described in (b)
so selects only from the legitimate possibilities). What is
the probability that the individual gains access to the
account?

d.Recalculate the probability in (c) if the first and last digits are 1 and 1, respectively.

### ---------------------------------------------

For part a): The total number of pins without restrictions is $10,000$

For part b): The number of pins in either ascending or descending order is $10 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$, because once the first digit is known, then the three other spots containing digits are already spoken for. The number of pins where each slot contains the same digit is $10 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$, because once the first digit is known there is only one option left to the rest of the slots. The number of pins that have their first and second slot occupied by 1 and 9, respectively, is $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot$. So, if R is the set that contains these restricted pins, then $|R| = 130$; and if N is the set that contains the non-restricted ones, meaning R and N are complementary sets, then $|N| = 10,000 - 130$. **Hence, the probability is then $P(N) = 9780/10000 = 0.9870.$ However, the answer is $0.9876$. What did I do wrong?**

For part c): The sample space, containing all of the outcomes of the experiment that will take place, is $|N|=9870$. When it says that the thief won't use the same pair of digits in each try, does that not allow him trying the pin 8 **5 2** 1 in one try and the pin 8 **2 5** 1 in another try?

Comment: Ascending or descending is $14$, not $20$. That takes care of the disagreement.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I didn't get 14 or 20, I got 10. Your saying the answer is 14, how did you get that?

Comment: @Eli: You got $2\cdot10=20$ for ascending and descending together, and André is saying that it should be $2\cdot7=14$ for both together.

Comment: Oh, I see. The 2 corresponds to the two choices (ascending or descending); and the 7 corresponds to the fact that you can't start the 4-digit pin with 7,8, or 9 when ascending, and you can't start a 4-digit pin with 0,1, or 2 when descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For b): Which is the descending sequence starting with $1$ that you counted?

For c): Good question; the problem is badly worded in that regard. Taking it literally, I'd tend to interpret it as referring to unordered pairs, but since it makes little sense to couple two different PINs in this manner, I suspect that they actually mean ordered pairs. However, note that the answer doesn't depend on this.

I understand neither why the question says that the thief knows the restrictions, nor why you say that the sample space has size $9870$. The thief knows that the first and last digits are $8$ and $1$, respectively; that's not compatible with any of the sequences excluded by the restrictions, and it doesn't allow for $9870$ possibilities.

Comment: I’d interpret is as referring to ordered pairs, partly from the language, and partly from the overall level of difficulty of the exercise.

Comment: @joriki I don't really understand what you are asking when you say, "Which is the descending sequence starting with 1 that you counted?"

Comment: @Eli: You wrote that there are $10$ descending sequences because the sequence is determined once the first digit is known. I took that to mean that there is exactly one descending sequence starting with each of the $10$ digits. I asked because I figured that in trying to exhibit the one that starts with $1$ you'd notice that there isn't one.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, a descending sequence couldn't begin with 0 or 2 either.

Comment: @Eli: Exactly. And $10-3=7$.

Comment: Since we corrected part a), the sample space for part c) will then be $9876$, because that is the total number of non-restricted combinations, one of which will be the combination the thief is looking for. What do you mean by unordered pairs and ordered pairs?

Comment: @Eli: I still don't understand what you mean by saying that that's the sample space. The thief knows that the first and last digits are $8$ and $1$, respectively, and he only varies the second and third digits. What does that have to do with the number $9876$ of possibilities calculated in part b)? About unordered and ordered pairs, see Wikipedia. Quite generally, that's a good place to look for definitions if you encounter terms you don't understand.

Comment: Oh, I think I see now. Since there are no restrictions on the digits we can use to fill slot 2 and 3 of the 4-digit pin, and we know the first and last, $1 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 1 =100$ is the number of pins containing 8 as its first digit and 1 as its last digit. We can also think of this number as 100 different trys, but the thief only has 3; that is, he can only use 3 different pin numbers of the 100. $3/100=.03. This is still wrong, though. The answer is $.0333$

Comment: @Eli: When you have a formatting mistake like above, you can still edit the comment for five minutes after you post it (there's an edit link at the end of the comment during this time). The answer can't be $.0333$, since that's $333/10000$, which is in reduced form and thus can't be written as $p/q$ with $q\le100$, but the answer must be of that form no matter how many of the $100$ possibilities we exclude. Perhaps they actually meant $0.0\bar3=3/90$, but I don't see how the rules could lead to a count of $90$ possibilities. Where did you get these answers? The online book doesn't have them.

Comment: Yes, I am very sorry. After I saw that I had made a mistake in that comment, more than five minutes had past. I am drawing my answers from the back of the book. And no, it isn't written as .03 repeated, it is written as .0333

Comment: @Eli: I found another version of the book online with the answers included. It has $.0337$ for d., which is also wrong, but can be interpreted as a rounded version of the correct result $3/89$ (see Metin's answer). So it seems they just round results without indicating it (which is rather bad style). So it seems likely that $0.0333$ is a rounded version of $3/90$. That leaves the question how they arrive at $90$ options. Perhaps they meant to say $1$ and $8$ instead of $8$ and $1$; then the birth year rule would lead to a count of $90$.

Comment: @Eli: That would also explain why part c already mentions that the thief knows the restrictions, even though that's irrelevant for the question as posed.

Answer (score 1):

For d): We have the case: $1$ * * $1$.

But the thief knows, by prohibition (i), it can not be $1111$. Thus he eleminates $1$ possibility.

Also he knows, by (iii), the second digit can not be $9$. There are exactly $10$ number of the form $19$ * $1$, namely, $1900$, $1910$, $1920$... So, at this stage he eleminates $10$ possibilities.

All in all, if he had no restrictions, there were $100$ choices for the form $1$ * * $1$. But he excluded $10 + 1 = 11$ of them and get 89 possible choices. Since he has 3 chances, the resulting possibility is $3/89$.

Answer (score 1):

For (c) he has 3 tries, and there are a total of 100 choices. There are 10 choices for the 2nd number and 10 choices for the 3rd number. Since the PIN begins with an 8 and ends with a 1, none of the restrictions apply.

- For his first try, there is a $1/100 = 0.0100$ probability of guessing the correct PIN.
- For his second try, there is a $1/99 \approx 0.0101$ probability.
- For his third try, there is a $1/98 \approx 0.0102$ probability.

So the total probability is $1/100 + 1/99 + 1/98 \approx 0.0303$.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents,

$10^4$ possibilities.

There are $14$ ascending and descending groups of $4$.

Keyspace $9,876$

If the badguy knows two of the four spaces, he only has to guess through entropy $10^2$.
(None of the restrictions meet up with the range 8xx1)

$3$ Tries in $100$

:)

Comment: (0123)(1234)(2345)(3456)(4567)(5678)(6789)

And then the reverse of those...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding part [c], I do not think that there is something wrong with the book. As **@Mack** said in one of his comments, thief has to guess only two second numbers. Since the given restrictions actually do not apply on this order of numbers, he has to guess among 100 (10*10) possible combinations of the numbers.

Since he has 3 tries, the probability that he will gain desired access is 3/100.

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F100), 3/100 is exactly 0.03, which is the same as written solution from the book.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

a)
There are 10,000 different combinations since each digit can go from 0-9 and since there are 4 digits in total then the answer will be 10x10x10x10 or 10^4= 10,000

b)
all 4 digits are identical this gives the combinations of 1111,2222,3333...,9999 so there are 10 combinations (total of 10)
cannot be consecutive ascending:0123,1234,2345,3456,4567,5678,6789 (total of 7)
cannot be consecutive descending:9876,8765,7654,6543,5432,4321,3210 (total of 7)
any sequence that starts with 19 so that gives to digits to work with 19_ _
10^2=100 same logic as for part (A)
so in total, there are (10+7+7+100) which gives 124 combinations that cannot be used
so 10,000-124=9876 and since its asking for a probability it would be 9876/10000 or 0.9876

c)
given that the first digit is 8 and the last digit is 1 we have 8__1
since there are 100 different combinations for the 2nd and 3rd digit and we have 3 tries it would be 3/100 or .030

d)
given that the pin starts with 1 and ends with 1 we have 1__1
the rules say it cannot repeat so 1111 isnt an option and it could start with 19_1
so there are 10 possible pins going from 1901 to 1991
so out of the 100 possible pins 11 of them are restricted. 100-11=89
so there is a 3/89 chance or 0.0337 of getting the pin within 3 tries.